# Solving a transcendental equation with FindRoot and making a contour plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following functions,

```
f[Cpl_, a_, EF_, V_, Jsd_, α_, β_, σ_, ϕ_][kp_] := 
  With[{kx = kp*Cos[σ], ky = kp*Sin[σ]},
    With[
      {θ = 
         ϕ - 
           If[α*kx >= 0, 
              ArcCos[β*ky/Sqrt[(α*kx)^2 + (β*ky)^2]], 
              2*Pi - ArcCos[β*ky/Sqrt[(α*kx)^2 + (β*ky)^2]]],
       kzdo = Sqrt[Cpl*(EF + (Jsd/2)) - kx^2 - ky^2],
       kzup = Sqrt[Cpl*(EF - (Jsd/2)) - kx^2 - ky^2],
       Qp = 
         Sqrt[Cpl*(V - EF + Sqrt[(α*kx)^2 + (β*ky)^2]) + kx^2 + ky^2],
       Qm = 
         Sqrt[Cpl*(V - EF - Sqrt[(α*kx)^2 + (α*ky)^2]) + kx^2 + ky^2]
      },
      4*
        (Sin[a*kzdo]*
          (kzup*(Qm + Qp + (Qm - Qp)*Cos[θ])*Cos[a*kzup] + 2*Qm*Qp*Sin[a*kzup]) +
        kzdo*Cos[a*kzdo]*(2*kzup*Cos[a*kzup] + 
          (Qm + Qp - (Qm - Qp)*Cos[θ])*Sin[a*kzup]))^2]];
```

and then I fix all variables except three of them,

```
CPl1 = 0.262227; 
a1 = 5.0000000000; 
EF1 = 2.600000000; 
V1 = EF1 + 0.500000000000; 
Jsd1 = 1.50000000000; 
ϕ1 = Pi/12; 
α1 = 1.0; 
β1 = 1.0;

function[En_, σ_][kp_] := f[CPl1, a1, En, En + 0.5, Jsd1, α1, β1, σ, ϕ1][kp]
```

I would like to solve this equation for fixed values of `En` & `σ` for `kp`. Function `NSolve` does not work, so I use `FindRoot` function. To use it, I plot my function using `Plot` and deduce where roots are "located" (careful analysis of regions says that there are 4 roots):

[image]

For instance, fixing `E=3.0` and `σ=0` method `FindRoot` gives me 4 roots.

Then, I chek my results. I plot implicit function `function=0` using `ContourPlot`:
[image]

It is clearly only two roots. I know that `ContourPlot` sometimes gives inaccurate plots and it can be fixed by plotting $\text{function}=\epsilon$, where, for instance, $\epsilon\sim 10^{-8}$. However, it does not solve my problem.

Accuracy of `FindRoot` says that value `function` is about $\sim 10^{-11}-10^{-14}$ in every root. I do not understand what is wrong with my code. How should I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary issue in this question is plotting resolution. Both `Plot` and `ContourPlot` sample the function to be plotted at a finite number of locations.  If none of these locations is sufficiently near a portion of the desired curve, then that portion may be missed.  In this case, greatly increasing `PlotPoints` and setting `MaxRecursion` yields,

```
Plot[function[3, 0][kp], {kp, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 400000, MaxRecursion -> 5, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {kp, fun}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Distinct roots are seen to occur at about 0.58, 0.77, 0.84, and 0.99.  Because the curve at 0.58 is tangent to the axis from above, `ContourPlot` is unlikely to find it unless `function` is equated to some small positive number.  Likewise, because the curve at 0.84 is tangent to the axis from below, `ContourPlot` is unlikely to find it unless `function` is equated to some small negative number.  The following finds both.

```
pltp = ContourPlot[function[En, 0][kp] == 10^-4, {En, 0, 4}, {kp, 0, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 250, MaxRecursion -> 3, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, FrameLabel -> {En, kp}];
pltm = ContourPlot[function[En, 0][kp] == -10^-4, {En, 0, 4}, {kp, 0, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 250, MaxRecursion -> 4, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, FrameLabel -> {En, kp}]
Show[pltp, pltm]
```

[image]

A vertical slice through the `ContourPlot` at `En = 3` exhibits the same four roots as in the first plot.  The fifth curve does not intersect `En = 3` and, therefore, is not a root of the curve in the first plot.

Comment: Comprehensive & clear. Thank you!